# Setting state at the root level from a component 2 layers deep

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

New to React so struggling with this.

I want to change a list based on a category chosen, however the Categories component is called by a Listing component which is called by the App component.

```
-App.js
 -Listing.js
  -Categories.js
```

I am setting the state of selectedCategory in the app.js file initially and it works as expected, however I want to update this state. I can update the state in the categories component but this only updates the state on the `<Category>` element. I want to update the state "globally" so I can access it everywhere.

Here's the Categories.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Categories extends Component {


handleCategoryClick = (id, e) => {
    console.log(id);

    this.setState({ selectedCategory:id });

}

render() {

return (
    <div className="tour-categories">

        <ul className="tour-categories-list">
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(1, e)}>Food &amp; Drink</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(2, e)}>Whisky Distilleries</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(3, e)}>TV &amp; Film Location</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(4, e)}>City Tour</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(5, e)}>Castles</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(6, e)}>Golf </li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(7, e)}>Shopping</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(8, e)}>Out Door Activities</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(9, e)}>Spa &amp; Wellness</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(10, e)}>Boat Tours &amp; Water Sports</li>
            <li onClick={(e) => this.handleCategoryClick(11, e)}>Zoo &amp; Aquariums</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
)
}
}

export default Categories;
```

The Listing.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Categories from './Categories.js';

class Listing extends Component {

render() {

return (
    <div>

        <Categories />

    </div>
)
}
}

export default Listing;
```

And the App.js component (relevant part)

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
 tours: {},
 selectedCategory: ""
};

loadData() {
fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({
        tours: json
    });
  })
```

}

```
 componentDidMount() {

 this.loadData();

}


render() {
 return (

    <div className="tour-container">

      <Listing />

     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your selected category through props

Something like that in App:

```
<Listing selected={this.state.selectedCategory} />
```

Then in your Listing, pass it to your Category

```
<Category selected={this.state.selectedCategory} />
```

Access it with this.props.selectedCategory inside Category (or listing)

If you need to update it from category ->

```
<Category selected={this.state.selectedCategory} onUpdate={this._handleUpdate} />
```

And to handle changes :

```
function _handleUpdate(updatedValue){
  this.props.onUpdate(updatedValue);
}
```

And do the same in Listing to get back into App.

Update the state in app when onUpdate from Listing.

And you are done ! ;)

Docs :
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Some explanations on Inline functions : 
https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass it to your children component

also in the

in category you define callback function update data then it pass to your Listing  then app so app we can access it as props so there should function